# How can I share mail boxes in Snow Leopard Server?

Tags: dovecot, osx-snow-leopard

is it possible to share mail boxes between users on Mac OS X Server 10.6.4? I know Dovecot can do this but It seems that Snow Leopard's Dovecot can't, can it?

Thanks

Philip

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot has full support for shared mailboxes since 1.2.0.
I guess there is 1.2.10 in the ports so why does it seem it can not do this?

Comment: I am asking for the build-in Dovevot in Snow Leopard Server or is it possible to upgrade it?